# How to execute some code in destructor *after* member are destroyed

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a "manager" class that has to do certain clean-up **after** the members are destroyed:

```
class Manager
{
    Member a, b;

    ~Manager()
    {
        // this code will be executed BEFORE the a and b destructors
        important_cleanup();
    }
};
```

The problem here is that `important_cleanup()` invalidates my variables `a` and `b`, so their destructors fail.

Is there a nice way around the problem?

**PS** I know I can define some kind of clenup member, and make it be the first created member of `Manager`, but this looks quite ugly and makes things order-dependent...

Comment: This definitely smells like a poor design...

Comment: Why in the world can't an invalid `Member` object be destructed? This makes no sense IMO, what's the reasoning behind this decision?

Comment: @CoryKramer, or buggy implementation of some policy.

Comment: @Dimaleks If you could explain in more concrete terms why this design is the way it is, we might be able to help better. (See also: XY problem.)

Comment: "Invalidates the members so the destructors fail"?  Is `important_cleanup()` freeing memory or resources that are associated with `a` and `b` instead of letting them clean up for themselves?

Comment: Perhaps make `a` and `b` `std::unique_ptr`s? That way `important_cleanup()` can assure their destruction by replacing `a` and `b` with `nullptr`s.

Comment: In concrete terms, `a` and `b` are CUDA arrays, that have their own destructors that free the memory nicely.
And `important_cleanup()` has to destroy CUDA context completely

Comment: @CoryKramer What would be an alternative design? Basically that is what I'm looking for! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relying on destruction order really isn't error-prone, assuming you also put a comment stating that the member order matters for the specific member. It's put in the language for a reason, so it's totally fine to use it.

That said, if you are uncomfortable relying on it, [destructors of members are called before those of the base classes,](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Destruction_sequence) so you can use a base class to do this:

```
class ManagerCleanup {
public:
    ~ManagerCleanup() {
        important_cleanup();
    }

private:
    some_native_resource resource;
};

// Might as well inherit privately
class Manager : private ManagerCleanup
{
    Member a, b;
};
```

Note that it's more idiomatic if you wrap the resource:

```
// Note: this could probably be a std::unique_ptr. std::unique_ptr can
// manage arbitrary resources, not just pointers.
class ItemRequiringCleanup {
public:
    // Ensure you implement/disable copy/move operations appropriately

    ~ItemRequiringCleanup() {
        important_cleanup();
    }

private:
    some_native_resource resource;
};

class ManagerCleanup {
private: // or protected:
    ItemRequiringCleanup resource;
};

// Might as well inherit privately
class Manager : private ManagerCleanup
{
    Member a, b;
};
```

Comment: Right, I like that much more than a cleanup member, thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't like the second variant, because it seems very error-prone, that's what I wrote in the text.

Comment: @Dimaleks Yes, you are right. Your question stated that you were seeking an alternative. Updated to reflect that